# Is this possible to record live streaming video in android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, video-recording

i am working live streaming video in android, i have completed the task to load the live streaming url, now i want to record the video which is playing on video view, is there anyway to achieve this? please help me.

Comment: Everything is possible, but you need to provide more information, and also try to be precise in your questions, in order for others to understand your questions and possibly provide answers.

Comment: The same question above. 
Did you fix your issue and how ? 
Please help me.

Comment: @NazarMerza Have any updates?

Answer (score -3):

try to use this

```
  public void onClick(View arg0) {

  Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);
 }
```